# Cannot Connect Mongodb with my server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Error : throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')} ${isOrAre} not supported`);

I am getting this error and my code is :
server .js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

I am not able to connect database with my server

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply connect with this code -

```js
mongoose.connect(uri, {
            useNewURLParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        })
        .then(() => console.log("We are ready with database"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(`Database connection error ${err}`));
```